# About write behaviour in Odoo 8

Tags: python-2.7, odoo, odoo-8

I have the model `stock.production.lot`. I added to this model two one2many fields, `incoming_moves` and `outgoing_moves`, both of them pointing to model `stock.move`. I have also added a float field named `qty` on `stock.move`.
And I added two computed fields in `stock.production.lot` which calculate the incoming and the outgoing quantity.

Now, I want to forbid lots whose outgoing quantity is higher than the incoming one. For this, I have made a constraint in `stock.move`. I know the most reasonable option would be make this constraint in `stock.production.lot`, but the problem I see is that in `@api.constrains` decorator I cannot use dot notation, so I can only write `@api.constrains('incoming_moves', 'outgoing_moves')`, and this means that if I modify the quantity of a move, this constraint is not even being executed.

So my constraint in `stock.move` is:

```
@api.one
@api.constrains('qty', 'restrict_lot_id')
def _check_qties(self):
    if (self.in_vqty - self.out_vqty) < 0:
        raise ValidationError(
            _('The incoming quantity (Kg) of the lot is lower than '
              'the outgoing one.')
        )
```

It seems to work great in any case, except for the following one: if I modify the quantity of several moves of the same lot at the same time (from the one2many field of the lot form), the ORM `write` method behaviour makes the constraint raise the error inspite of the quantities are OK.

> **Example**
>
> I have a lot which an incoming move (InM1) of 8 and three outgoing
>   moves (OutM1, OutM2, OutM3) of 1, 3 and 4 (lot quantity => 8 - (1+3+4) = 0, it is OK). I go to the form of this
>   lot and edit the one2many of `outgoing_moves`. From there, I set OutM1
>   to 2 and OutM3 to 3, so the total quantity of the lot will be 8 -
>   (2+3+3), which is 0 and is OK too. But, when I click on *Save* button, the
>   constraint raises the error. Why?
>
> This is what is happening: after clicking on *Save*, ORM `write`
>   method of `stock.move` is called. First time, it wants to update
>   OutM1, and it does it, but just after that, the constraint is checked
>   and as OutM3 has not been updated yet, it receives 8 - (2+3+4), and
>   that is the reason of the error raising.

So I tried to remove the constraint and do the check inside ORM `write` method, but I face the same problem. I put my checks after the super, but the ORM `write` method is called twice, the first time to update OutM1 and the second one to update OutM3. Between those actions the exception is raised too, due to the same reason I explained above.

How could I solve this?

Comment: Shouldn't you be doing the validations against the whole batch of records instead of each record one by one, in order to determine whether the whole operation is valid? Eg.: `@api.multi`

Comment: That is what I would like to do, but for checking the whole batch of records I need to apply the constraint in `stock.production.lot` (which has the one2many fields pointing to `stock.move`). The problem is that the `@api.constrains` gives me error if I tell it to depend on `incoming_moves.qty` and `outgoing_moves.qty`, so how can I do that?

Comment: Just an untested idea: How about making related fields `incoming_moves_qty` and `outgoing_moves_qty` to their corresponding `*_move.qty`, and setting the constrains on them?